# Linq Expression change data storing

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have the following code:

```
public class MyContext:DbContext
{
    DbSet<ABFoo> ABFoo { get; set; }
    DbSet<CDFoo> CDFoo { get; set; }
}
```

ABFoo and CDFoo are classes with same members.
I have now and this query:

```
var t = context.ABFoo.Where(a => a.ID == 10);
```

I want to make ABFoo table changed dinamically in this way

```
var t = context.ABFoo.Where(a => a.ID == 10).OnThePrefixTable("CD");
```

Even if query is executed on ABFoo table, i have to switch to the CDFoo table.
I know i have to use ExpressionVisistors and change the "object", but do not know well what should i do!
Thank you a lot!

Comment: you want to put the data where ID = 10 from ABFoo in table CDFoo, did I understand well ?

Answer (score 1):

you could use a lib like AutoMapper https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper

Initialize it with

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ABFoo, CDFoo>();
```

and use

```
var cdFooList = Mapper.Map(context.ABFoo.SingleOrDefault(a => a.ID == 10), new CDFoo());
```

or if you return a list

```
var cdFoo = Mapper.Map(context.ABFoo.Where(a => a.Id == 10).ToList(), new List<CDFoo>());
```

Comment: This may be a solution, since i already use automapper. But in this way i will lose automatic Entity Framework dependency tracker. Updating object using SaveChanges may result in an error. I would like to preserve this modifying update and select expressions!